# Как прописать динамический margin через calc() CSS?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В зависимости от ширины окна нужно менять отступ слева.
Сейчас это сделано через @media

```
table{
    margin: 0 0 0 2%;
}

@media (min-width: 1540px){
    table{
        margin: 0 0 0 15%;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 2000px){
    table{
        margin: 0 0 0 25%;
    }
}
```

Как это можно реализовать через calc() в CSS?

Comment: а vw не подходит?

Answer (score 2):

через Calc можно реализовать линейные (непрерывные) вычисления, но не задать дискретность/интервалы изменений. Т.е., если вам именно надо чтобы маржин слева был 25% на экранах свыше 2000, 15% - на 1540...2000 и 2% - на всех остальных, то делать надо именно так, как вы и сделали - через медиа квери. Вот когда в Calc() можно будет передавать не только четыре основных математических действия, но логические операторы и формулы функций, тогда и можно будет вернуться к этой теме и подумать...

Как вариант, если вас устроит линейное и непрерывное приращение/изменение - сделать маржин в процентах от ширины окна (вьюпорта), как вам подсказали в комментариях:

```
table{margin: 0 0 0 25 vw;}
```

При ширине, например, в 1540 пикселей маржин будет составлять 385 px, а при 2000 - 500 px, но промежуточные ширины окна дадут вам и промежуточные результаты.  Ровно того же эффекта вы добьетесь, задав `padding-left:25%`родительскому контейнеру таблицы (если он равен ширине окна, конечно).